# Redshift UNLOAD Select Distinct creates larger zip file vs Select *?

Tags: gzip, distinct, amazon-redshift

I'm seeing a very strange thing with Redshift UNLOAD and wondering if anyone else has seen this or has an explanation for it.

I have one UNLOAD query. When I Unload using 'Select Distinct' with GZIP, the files unloaded add up to three times as large as if I do a 'Select *' (no distinct) with GZIP.

Here's the query:

```
UNLOAD ('SELECT DISTINCT <29 fields> FROM public.mytable WHERE myfield = 999') 
TO 's3://myBucket/myfile.txt' CREDENTIALS 'mycreds' DELIMITER '\t' 
GZIP PARALLEL TRUE MAXFILESIZE 256 MB ALLOWOVERWRITE;
```

The output of this query adds up to 26GB.

If I change it to **'Select *'**, the output is 8GB. Also, Select Distinct creates 14 zip files, while Select * creates only 5 zip files.

This is contradictory as one would expected the deduped files to be smaller.

I'm thinking GZIP Distinct is creating a much larger zip dictionary file than GZIP Select *.

The question is, why?

Comment: interesting, please can you add some metrics? number of columns, anything else in the query, your unload commands in full? the size of the gz files in s3? My guess is that the distinct one is NOT gzipped (as its 3x bigger) so can you download and view the files raw in e.g. notepad++ to see what they look like?

Comment: are you sure `select *` produces a single file? I think `select distinct` produces a single file while `select *` will produce multiple files

Comment: Edited with more info.

Comment: Please show both commands that you are comparing, and a sample of the output in each case (eg a header and one row of data) to show that they are outputting the same information. If you are concerned that one of them is missing rows, you could also count the rows (eg via Athena) to check if data is missing. When you say it "adds up to 26GB", is that compressed or uncompressed?